# Combining Barabasi-Albert model and Watts-Strogatz model in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to combine [Watts-Strogatz model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts%E2%80%93Strogatz_model) with half the required edges and a [Barabasi-Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) with the other half of the remaining edges? I'm trying to do this in python, but I'm not really sure how I should start off as I'm really weak at coding so I'm seeking some advice here. 
I'm actually trying to convert a MATLAB code(as shown below) to a python code.
MATLAB code:

```
function B = custom207 ()
% This file provides a simulation for Facebook network .
N =4039;
mean_d =2;
% A WS - model is used as initial network of BA - model .
initial_network = WattsStrogatz (3850 ,1 ,0.05) ;
% The following part is the model growth of BA - model . Nodes are added to
this network until the number of nodes reaches 4039.
% A is the adjacency matrix , it is pre - allocated for efficiency .
A = zeros (N , N ) ;
A (1:3850 ,1:3850) = initial_network ;
% This step use the exactly same method as BA model except the number of
nodes attached to a new node ( which is mean_d ) is increasing by 4( this
is obtained by trying different values ).
for i =3851: N
prob_vec = sum ( A ) / sum ( sum ( A ) ) ;
attachment = unique ( randsample (N , mean_d , true , prob_vec ) ) ;
A (( i -1) * N + attachment ) =1;
A =( A +A ') >0;
mean_d = mean_d +4;
end
```

My python code as of now is:

```
#initialise values
#WS model used as initial network of BA model  
N = 4039
mean_k = 2
initial_network = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(3850,mean_k,0.05)
nx.draw(initial_network,node_size=0.5,node_color='blue', alpha=0.2,edge_colour='red')

#model growth of BA model. Nodes added to this network till total 4039 nodes
#Allocate adjacency matrix
adjacency = np.zeros((N,N))
initial_network = adjacency(1:3850, 1:3850)
```

So I'm stuck at how I can attach the nodes from BA model

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I am not really familiar with the networkx module (except for plotting graphs). But I think, the easiest way to go on would be to simply extract the adjacency matrix like you did, but then go on using numpy.

```
    import numpy as np
    import networkx as nx
    N = 4039
    A = np.zeros((N,N))
    mean_k = 2
    initial_network = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(3850,mean_k,0.05)
    # nx.draw(initial_network,node_size=0.5, node_color='blue',  alpha=0.2, edge_colour='red')
    A[:3850, :3850] = nx.to_numpy_array(initial_network)
    for i in range(3850, N):
        prob_vec = np.sum(A, 1) / np.sum(A) # Be aware of the differen conventions in Matlab and python functions!
        attachment = np.unique(np.random.choice(np.arange(N), mean_k, replace=True, p=prob_vec))
        temp = A.copy().flatten(order='F') # Probably there is nicer array indexing than this detour.
        temp[i * N + attachment] = 1
        A = np.reshape(temp, A.shape, order='F') # Here I am especially not sure about the order..
        A = (A + A.T) > 0
        mean_k += 4
    out_graph = nx.DiGraph(A)
```

Pleas note, I just tested this code in so far, that I know it works. I am not sure, whether the results are compatible with what you are expecting... 
But I hope this is enough to get you started! Always be aware of the different indexing and reshaping, etc. in Matlab and Python, i.e. starting at 0 and Fortran vs. C conventions when working with arrays.